# How can I place my target view on top of the tab bar?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitabbar

I want to place my **targetView** right on top of the **tab bar**. I created a **XIB-File** with a **targetLabel** and a **cancelButton**.

I tried to place my [targetView](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JyXBd.png) programmatically on top of my **tab bar** but I can´t figure out how to do it without space between them.

```
[self addOverlayView:self.targetView x:0 y:self.view.frame.size.height - self.targetView.frame.size.height - 10];
```

***addOverview*** is a func I made to place a view where ever you want:

```
- (void)addOverlayView:(UIView*)v x:(CGFloat)x y:(CGFloat)y
{
    v.hidden = YES;
    CGRect vFrame = v.frame;
    vFrame.origin.x = x;
    vFrame.origin.y = y;
    
    if ((v.autoresizingMask & UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth) != 0) {
        vFrame.size.width = topView.bounds.size.width;
    }
    v.frame = vFrame;
    [v.layer setTransform:CATransform3DMakeTranslation(0, 0, OVERLAY_TRANSLATION_Z)];
    
    [overlayView addSubview:v];
    
}
```

I don´t know if this was the right approach but it works for me (so far).

What do I have to change in so that my ***targetView*** is right on top of my ***tabBar***?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove that -10 and check

```
  [self addOverlayView:self.targetView x:0 y:self.view.frame.size.height - self.targetView.frame.size.height];
```

Comment: This attempt seems to be more brute force then ideal. I could change the value so that it fits but when changing the device it does no work